# Flushing user sessions on start up of a Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-redis, spring-session

I am now persisting user sessions in Redis in my spring boot application. I would like to flush all sessions from Redis on application startup.

As of now, I am invalidating the sessions on application startup as follows:

```
  @EventListener
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
  }
```

Not only I would like to invalidate the user sessions from Redis, but I would also like to flush them too.

In this context, I have found a few related posts in SO, but did not get an idea regarding how to flush session entries from Redis on startup. Could anyone please help here?